# IllustratorCC - how to align lines of text *along* curve? Not directly on path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment, text-on-path

First question here, so hopefully I'm doing it right. I'm fairly new to AI - current graphic design student. I'm familiar with text along a path, but am still learning various aspects of the program. I'm working in CC

In what I'm working on, I have a circular path. I'm trying to align text with it (not on the path itself) but in a vertical manner, with multiple lines. The attached image shows exactly what I am going for. What is the easiest and most efficient way to achieve this? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Draw a circle, and then draw path from the centre of that circle to outside the circle.
2. Type some text on the path. Use tabs and spaces to separate the outer text from the inner text.
3. Then in the appearance panel, click fx > distort and transform > transform
4. Add a rotational transform like this.

[image]

5. Then click Object > Expand Appearance.
6. Now you can edit the text on the other paths

[image]

Comment: If you link those text threads then you can just paste all of that text in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary you can not. However, you can make a sequence of paths that is radial to your path and then make those linked text on path items. You can get equally spaced lines with a very wide brush and dashing. Then its just a matter of turning all those to text on path elements and linking them to one thread.

[image]

**Image 1**: Text radially on path.

Its a bit painful to do manually, so if you find yourself doing this a lot i suggest you script this.

[image]

**Image 2**: The text therads visualized.

PS: it may be easier to edit the lines somewhere else. As reading the text is a bit cumbersome in this orientation.